# Autoscaling y-axis according to x-range slider in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, slider, autoscalemode

I am using plotly for plotting the time-series data where x-axis representing date and y axis some numbers and I've created a slider for selecting date ranges, I want to auto scale the values of y-axis according to the selected date range. How can I achieve this? Here is my code.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")
df.columns = [col.replace("AAPL.", "") for col in df.columns]

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.High)))

# Set title
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Time series with range slider and selectors"
)

# Add range slider
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                     label="6m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="YTD",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1y",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)

fig.show()
```